# replace text in a file from textline in other file

Tags: xml, regex, linux, replace

here is my question , im using ubuntu , and im trying to replaces text in a xml file .. from a txt that i have all changes that i made ,an example

in replace.txt file i have this

```
    nameofsearch  | nameforreplace
    nameofsearch1 | nameforreplace1 
    nameofsearch2 | nameforreplace2
```

this is the format that the software uses for search and replace

and on the xml file, i have the nameofsearch

this was done by a soft made on .net, that i can't run on linux , so this is my question , how can i do that , using bash , or any other thing like that.

thanks , sebastian.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7974779/using-sed-to-find-and-replace-in-bash-for-loop/7978660#7978660

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tool you are looking for is [sed](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?sed). If you want to replace str1 with str2 in file1 and save the result in file2, run:

```
sed s/str1/str2 < file1 > file2
```

You need to escape some special characters because sed parses the str1 as a regular expression.

In your case, two steps are needed. The first step transforms your `replace.txt` into a sed script file witch I call `replace.sed`.

```
sed "s/\s*|\s*/\//g"  "replace.txt" | sed "s/\w*\/\w*/s\/&\/g/" > replace.sed
```

The first sed call transforms your pipes (and surrounding whitespaces) into slashes `|`->`/`. The second call surrounds your search/replace strings with sed syntax. `replace.sed` should look like

```
s/nameofsearch/nameforreplace/
s/nameofsearch1/nameforreplace1/
s/nameofsearch2/nameforreplace2/
```

The second step is to execute sed with the given script file on your xml file.

```
sed -f replace.sed test.xml > replaced.xml
```

Comment: i have a list of replacementes that i have to do in the xml file , and this replacements r in replace.txt like this :
name_for_search | name_for_replace theres another way that i can read the txt file and then make the replacement on the xml

Comment: If it worked, please mark it as the answer to your question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might perhaps try using [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/) to run a .Net application on Linux.

You could use [AWK](http://www.gnu.org/s/gawk/) to do your replacement, or [Sed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed), or since your data is XML, use [XSLT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xslt)

I don't understand if you want to replace all occurrence of all the names you are searching, or only the first occurrence of the first name which is found.

Is the `replace.txt` file, or the XML file you are processing, huge?

Comment: hi basile , thanks for your answaer , i will explain in better way:
in replace.txt , i have this : 
name_for_search1 | name_for_replace1
name_for_search2 | name_for_replace2
.